# How in a single playbook become root as well as application user

Tags: ansible

I have a requirement to setup an application and for that I need to install Nginx as root and then run another Java application as a different application user.

The condition for this is, I have a privileged user "priv_suer" which has sudo and I'm running the playbook as this user as I need to install and configure Nginx. But my application user is different from this user "app_user" which is unprivileged application only user.

The issue I'm facing is, this app_user needs password to become app_user. So in my case I need two passwords one is to become root and another one to become app_user.

I referred [Understanding privilege escalation: become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation-become) and only option I could find was "*ansible_become_password*".

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that privilege escalation can help. My solution is:

- Declare different groups for servers running your Java applications and servers you want to install Nginx. In your case, the two groups can share the same servers.

  Here below I give an example of `inventory.yml` file:

```
all:
  children:
    app:
      hosts:
        127.0.0.1:
      vars:
        ansible_become_pass: app_user@123
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
        ansible_user: app_user

    nginx:
      hosts:
        127.0.0.1:
      vars:
        ansible_become_pass: root@123
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
        ansible_user: root
```

- An example of playbook is as follow:

```
- hosts: app
  tasks:
    - name: Install Java app
      become: yes

- hosts: nginx
  tasks:
    - name: Install NGINX
      become: yes
```

- Finally, run your ansible playbook with an inventory provided using `-i` option:

```
ansible-playbook -i etc/ansible/inventory.yml etc/ansible/playbook.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and this sounds cool. Heading to give this a try. Will update the status soon.